# initializing arrays that is defined in classes

Tags: c++

My app includes array of structure data. This is defined in the class.  How do I initialize this array?

```
typedef struct _API_ERRORS
{
    PLX_STATUS  code; //enum
    char       *text;
} API_ERRORS;
```

In class this is defined.

```
API_ERRORS Api_Errors[];
```

Can I initialize this in the constructor?

Comment: The array needs a size to be a member of the class. But you should prefer `std::array` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    CODE1,
    CODE2,
    CODE3
} PLX_STATUS;

typedef struct _API_ERRORS
{
    PLX_STATUS  code; //enum
    char       *text;
} API_ERRORS;

API_ERRORS ApiErrors[] = 
{
    {   CODE1, "Error 1"},
    {   CODE2, "Error 2"},
    {   CODE3, "Error 3"},
};
```

I just added the enum typedef to have some values to fill in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You want to initialize a variable(an array of structure variables) inside a class?

If the class was written by you,there are many ways to do this.

1. Write a default constructor yourself for the class.
2. Write a parameterized constructor for the class that accepts an "array of structure" as argument.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is used in the following two versions of sample code.

```
// with struct constructor
class Test {
    typedef enum {PLX_1, PLX_2} PLX_STATUS;
    typedef struct _API_ERRORS
    {
        PLX_STATUS  code; //enum
        char       *text;
        _API_ERRORS(PLX_STATUS code, char* text):code(code),text(text){};
    } _API_ERRORS;
public:
    Test() {
        array.push_back(_API_ERRORS(PLX_1, "plx1"));
        array.push_back(_API_ERRORS(PLX_2, "plx2"));
    }
private:
    vector<_API_ERRORS> array;
};

// without struct constructor
class Test {
    typedef enum {PLX_1, PLX_2} PLX_STATUS;
    typedef struct _API_ERRORS
    {
        PLX_STATUS  code; //enum
        char       *text;
    } _API_ERRORS;
public:
    Test() {
        array.push_back({PLX_1, "plx1"});
        array.push_back({PLX_2, "plx2"});
    }
private:
    vector<_API_ERRORS> array;
};
```